# Get one record per ID

Tags: sql, left-join

I'm trying to retrieve data from 2 tables A&B.

```
(select * from tableA a LEFT JOIN tableB b on a.idA = b.idA)
```

, there are multiple data rows in B for each PrimaryKey from A. But I want to get only the first record for every ID from tableA. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets so there is no *first* row.  But you can get an arbitrary row or specific row based on an ordering column using window functions:

```
select *
from tableA a LEFT JOIN
     (select b.*,
             row_number() over (partition by idA order by <ordering col>) as seqnum
      from tableB b
     ) b
     on a.idA = b.idA and seqnum = 1
```